# Delegate not being called when passing back data between Table View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I am trying to create a setting page for an app that uses Table View Controllers to pass data back changing the detailed text label of the first view controller depending on the text of the selected row of the second Table View Controller. I put a NSLog in under my delegate method on the initial Table View Controller and it is not being called. I am very stuck, any help is greatly appreciated!

Initial VC .h:

```
//  EditAlarmTVC.h (Initial table view controller .h file)
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AlarmSoundTVC.h"

@interface EditAlarmTVC : UITableViewController <AlarmSoundDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *offMethodCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *repeateCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *alarmLabelCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *alarmSoundCell;
@property (strong) NSManagedObjectModel *alarm;

- (IBAction)cancelSetAlarm:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveSetAlarm:(id)sender;

@end
```

Initial VC .m:

```
//EditAlarmTVC.m (Initial table view controller.m file)

#import "EditAlarmTVC.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface EditAlarmTVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *detailedTextLabels;

@end

@implementation EditAlarmTVC

@synthesize alarm;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"offMethod"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"timePicker"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"repeateLabelSoundCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"deleteAlarmCell"];
    self.detailedTextLabels =[NSMutableArray array];
    [self.detailedTextLabels addObject:@"Off"];
    [self.detailedTextLabels addObject:@"Never"];
    [self.detailedTextLabels addObject:@"Wake up, get up!"];
    [self.detailedTextLabels addObject:@"Default"];

}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.offMethodCell.detailTextLabel setText:[self.detailedTextLabels objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.repeateCell.detailTextLabel setText:[self.detailedTextLabels objectAtIndex:1]];
    [self.alarmLabelCell.detailTextLabel setText:[self.detailedTextLabels objectAtIndex:2]];
    [self.alarmSoundCell.detailTextLabel setText:[self.detailedTextLabels objectAtIndex:3]]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)sendSelection:(NSString *)selectedAlarm{
      NSLog(@"hello"); 
    [self.detailedTextLabels replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:selectedAlarm];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =nil;
    id delegat = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegat respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegat managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if(indexPath.section ==2 & indexPath.row==0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"repeateSegue" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.section ==2 & indexPath.row==1){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"alarmLabelSegue" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.section ==0 & indexPath.row==0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"offMethodSegue" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.section ==2 & indexPath.row==2){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"alarmSoundSegue" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.section ==3 & indexPath.row==0){
        //DELETE ALARM
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm"];
    NSDate *timeNSDate = [self.datePicker date];
    NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:timeNSDate];

    NSDateFormatter *amPmFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [amPmFormatter setDateFormat:@"a"];
    NSDate *amPmNSDate = [self.datePicker date];
    NSString *amPmString = [amPmFormatter stringFromDate:amPmNSDate];



        NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"time == %@", timeString];
        NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"amPm == %@", amPmString];
        NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"offMethod == %@", self.offMethodCell.detailTextLabel.text];
        NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"repeate == %@", self.repeateCell.detailTextLabel.text];
        NSPredicate *p5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alarmSound == %@", self.alarmSoundCell.detailTextLabel.text];

        NSPredicate *p6 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alarmLabel == %@", self.alarmLabelCell.detailTextLabel.text];


        NSPredicate *alarmsPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:alarmsPredicate];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items)
        {
            [context deleteObject:managedObject];
        }

    EditAlarmTVC *goToEditAlarmTVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setAlarmVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:goToEditAlarmTVC animated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    } else
        return;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"alarmSoundSegue"])
    {
        AlarmSoundTVC *alarmSoundTVC = [[AlarmSoundTVC alloc]init];
        [alarmSoundTVC setDelegate:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Second VC .h:

```
//AlarmSoundTVC.h (Second table view controller .h file)

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AlarmSoundDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) sendSelection:(NSString *)selectedAlarm;
@end

@interface AlarmSoundTVC : UITableViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AlarmSoundDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Second VC .m:

```
// AlarmSoundTVC.m (Second table view controller .m file)

#import "AlarmSoundTVC.h"
#import "EditAlarmTVC.h"

@interface AlarmSoundTVC ()

@end

@implementation AlarmSoundTVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell =[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(indexPath)];
    NSString *selectedAlarm = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [self.delegate sendSelection:selectedAlarm] ;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
//- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
//    }

@end
```

I am sorry if there is some extra unnecessary code in there. I am a bit new and wanted to be sure I provided plenty of information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `prepareForSegue` you are setting the delegate on a new, local, instance of `AlarmSoundTVC`, that will be discarded as soon as the method exits.  You need to use the instance that is going to be presented, which can be accessed via the `destinationViewController` property of the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"alarmSoundSegue"])
    {
        AlarmSoundTVC *alarmSoundTVC = (AlarmSoundTVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [alarmSoundTVC setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: @K.Crom Please accept this answer by ticking it with green tick on the left.